# Minecraft forge 1.14.4: missing library error (snapshot) in eclipse

Tags: java, minecraft, snapshot, minecraft-forge

I am trying to start modding Minecraft using Forge 1.14.4 but because of a "missing library" which is a snapshot, I will not be able to.

I have tried relentless online research but it never comes up.

In build.gradle, I noticed a part saying: 
 mappings channel: 'snapshot', version: '20190719-1.14.3'

The files being missing is preventing the project from being built.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be caused by having the wrong version of Java on your system path.

First, make sure you have the right JDK installed - jdk1.8.0_202 currently works for me. Download and install it if you haven't already.

Next, make sure it's the first version of Java in your path.

In Windows 10, press start, type 'Edit the system environment variables", and click Environment Variables.

Look for Path in the the System variables (the lower half of the screen, not the top half which may also have a Path variable).

There may be multiple lines that reference Java. On my computer I had two: `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin`. I deleted the first reference.

Open a new console and run the gradlew commands from README.txt again

Answer (score 0):

Some library is missing. Run the command `gradlew eclipse` after navigating into your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Is `vecmath` inside your build paths? I often had problems with it, but you can implement it manually.